# Prove or disprove: $\lvert\mathcal{R}\rvert=\lvert\mathcal{R}^{-1}\rvert$

Tags: relations, cardinals

Prove or disprove:

> If $\mathcal{R}$ is a relation then
>   $\lvert\mathcal{R}\rvert=\lvert\mathcal{R}^{-1}\rvert$.

---

I think it is true but I do not know how to prove it.

Facts:

- $\mathcal{R}^{-1}=\{(y,x)\mid(x,y)\in\mathcal{R}\}$.
- $\mathcal{R}\subseteq A\times B$.
- $\lvert\mathcal{R}\rvert\leq\lvert A\times B\rvert$.
- $(x,y)\in\mathcal{R}\implies(x,y)\in A\times B$.

I do not know how to define $\mathcal{R}$. I would know it if it is an equivalence relation, but it is not necessary like an equivalence relation.

Comment: Prove that $f(\,(x,y)\,)=(y,x) $  is a bijection from $R$ to $R^{-1}.$

Comment: @DanielWainfleet do you mean that we need to prove that $f\colon\mathcal{R}\to\mathcal{R}^{-1}$ defined by $f(x,y)=(y,x)$ is a bijection i.e. it is injective and surjective? Don't we need to prove first that $f$ is a function?

Comment: It's already a function because we are assigning to each $(x, y)$ a unique $f(x, y)$.  And, yes, all you need is to prove that $f$ is a bijection.

Comment: Yes of course we must confirm that it IS a function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

${\cal R}^{-1}$ is obtained from ${\cal R}$ by "flipping" all the ordered pairs in ${\cal R}$.  This leaves the number of the ordered pairs unchanged.

Comment: Thanks! Hm, that is a formal proof?

Comment: No.  The formal proof would be to prove that the mapping $(x, y) \mapsto (y, x)$ (the formalization of "flipping") from ${\cal R}$ to ${\cal R}^{-1}$ is a bijection (the formalization of "leaving the set cardinality unchanged").  BTW, is ${\cal R}$ finite?  Even if it is not, the formalization I give here is valid.

Comment: I would like to prove that the mapping is inyective and surjective, but I do not know how. For injectivity, we need to prove that $f(x_1,y_1)=f(x_2,y_2)\implies(x_1,y_1)=(x_2,y_2)$.

Comment: The statement says nothing about the cardinality order of $\mathcal{R}$.

Comment: In that case, what is $|{\cal R}|$?

Comment: I do not know what do you mean. I need to prove that if $(x_1,y_2)=(x_1,y_2)$ using $f(x_1,y_2)=f(x_2,y_2)$ but I do not know how.

Comment: If $(y_2, x_2) = (y_1, x_1)$, then $y_2 = y_1$ and $x_1 = x_2$, and therefore
$$
(x_2, y_2) = (x_1, y_1).
$$